# Why does *ngIf seem to break my reactive form? How do I handle conditional Inputs and validation in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

What I want to accomplish is for the form to change as the user changes the form type from the radio.

Standard basically has 2 selects (one classic and a fancier one, made with ng-select) and custom has a simple classic text input.

I am trying to change the form's functionality dynamically as the form type changes using the radio.

Besides trying to use formBuilder.group, I also tried using .setValidators on the individual inputs, but the result is the same: when I change the radio and the custom_channel_name input is shown i get this console error "Error: Cannot find control with name: 'custom_channel_name'"

What am I doing wrong and how do I properly handle reactive forms in this fashion?

What I have so far looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRsTq.png , https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4dnv.png

[ component.html ]

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="organizationChannelForm" (ngSubmit)="submitOrganizationChannelsForm()">
    <div *ngIf="isChannelTypeStandard" class="grid gap-4 grid-cols-2">
      <!-- <form-picker label="Countries" [values]="selectCountriesSources" labelField="name" valueField="warehouse_id"
        formControlName="warehouse_id"></form-picker> -->
      <div>
        <label for="channel_id" class="text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 block w-full pb-1 text-sm">Channel</label>
        <select [(ngModel)]="selectedChannel" id="channel_id" formControlName="channel_id"
          class="block w-full dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300 form-input">
          <option *ngFor="let channel of selectChannelsSources" [value]="channel">{{ channel }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="countries_ids" class="text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 block w-full pb-1 text-sm">Countries</label>
        <ng-select [items]="selectCountriesSources" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountries"
          [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }" id="countries_ids" [multiple]="true" bindLabel="name"
          name="countries_ids"></ng-select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!isChannelTypeStandard">
      <label for="custom_channel_name" class="text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 block w-full pb-1 text-sm">Custom Channel</label>
        <input class="form-input block w-full dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300"
        type="text" id="custom_channel_name" formControlName="custom_channel_name">
    </div>
    <div class="flex mt-5">
      <div class="flex ml-auto items-center">
        <span class="dark:text-gray-400">Channel Type</span>
        <div class="ml-6 flex">
          <label class="flex items-center cursor-pointer">
            <input [(ngModel)]="isChannelTypeStandard" [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }" (change)="updateOrganizationChannelForm($event)"
              type="radio" class="form-radio text-purple-600 h-4 w-4" name="channelType" [value]="true">
            <span class="dark:text-gray-300 font-medium ml-2">Standard</span>
          </label>
          <label class="flex items-center cursor-pointer ml-4">
            <input [(ngModel)]="isChannelTypeStandard" [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }" (change)="updateOrganizationChannelForm($event)"
              type="radio" class="form-radio text-purple-600 h-4 w-4" name="channelType" [value]="false">
            <span class="dark:text-gray-300 font-medium ml-2">Custom</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ml-8 min-w-0 text-white flex flex-col items-end rounded-lg shadow-xs">
        <button type="submit" aria-label="add" [disabled]="organizationChannelForm.errors || organizationChannelForm.pristine"
          class="flex items-end justify-between px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-white transition-colors duration-150 bg-purple-600 border border-transparent rounded-lg active:bg-purple-600 hover:bg-purple-700 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-purple disabled:bg-grey-600">
          Assign Channel
          <fa-icon class="ml-2" [icon]="icons.plus"></fa-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[ component.ts ]

```
export class OrganizationChannelsComponent implements OnInit {

  selectChannelsSources: Array<string> = ["eMag Marketplace", "Vtex", "Shopify", "Magento1", "Magento2", "WooCommerce", "Prestashop", "TeamShare", "Gomag", "Opencart", "MerchantPro", "Cscart", "Allegro", "Idosell", "ChannelAdvisor", "Shoprenter", "Transfer", "Defecte/Defects", "Manual Order"];
  selectCountriesSources: Array<Country> = [];
  icons = {
    close: faTimes,
    plus: faPlus
  }

  organizationChannelForm!: FormGroup;

  selectedCountries: Array<Country> = [];
  selectedChannel: Channel | undefined;
  isChannelTypeStandard: boolean = true;

  @Input() organizationId!: ID;

  organizationChannels$: Observable<OrganizationChannel[]> = new BehaviorSubject<OrganizationChannel[]>([]);
  channels$: Observable<Channel[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Channel[]>([]);

  constructor(
    private organizationChannelsService: OrganizationsChannelsService,
    private organizationChannelsQuery: OrganizationChannelsQuery,
    private countriesService: CountriesService,
    private toasterService: ToasterService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.organizationChannelForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      channel_id: ['', Validators.required],
    });

    this.organizationChannelsService.getOrganizationChannels(this.organizationId).subscribe();
    this.organizationChannels$ = this.organizationChannelsQuery.selectOrganizationChannels(this.organizationId as number);
    this.countriesService.get().subscribe(countries => this.selectCountriesSources = countries);
  }

  updateOrganizationChannelForm() {
    if (this.isChannelTypeStandard) {
      this.organizationChannelForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        channel_id: ['', Validators.required],
      });
    }
    else {
      this.organizationChannelForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        custom_channel_name: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]
      });
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please provide stackblitz url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation to the rescue! here is the official link to creating dynamic forms:
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms

basically you need formArray instead of formGroup for all the controls that are going to be conditionally visible on UI, read the docs and if it becomes difficult to understand then let me know I'll create a demo.